# I imported obj file but it seems it imported as single mesh?

Tags: export, import

A scene exported from 3ds Max as .obj is imported as single mesh in Blender. How can I get separate objects like in 3ds Max?

3ds Max

[image: 3ds max]

Blender

[image: blender]

Comment: Then you probably exported it as single object.

Comment: but in 3dsmax there is no option as to export it in single mesh

Comment: and there is no option i guess in blender to import obj as single mesh

Comment: How about the hierarchy in that object? It might be separated if the structure is well constructed

Answer (score 1):

Your .obj file likely doesn't separate objects using the [`o` attribute followed by the object name or `g` attribute followed by the group name](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/). Either one of those are needed to separate the scene into separate meshes. There seem to be several post in the Autodesk forums regarding the topic of exporting obj as separate meshes, you may find a solution there. Since I don't own a license of 3ds Max, I can't test whether one of them works.

In case 3ds Max doesn't provide a good option to accomplish this, perhaps another file format is better suited, e.g. .fbx, .dae, .ply, .gltf to name a few.

Comment: thank you so much for your answers but i figured it as a bug in 2.80 version , so i tried in another version 2.79 and its solved again thanks for answers

Comment: Does it import them as separate objects in 2.79? In that case it would be interesting to see the file and possibly file a bug report.